# Ajax data is not being sent to controller function (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am sending the `id` of dom element as `ajax` data to laravel controller but `Request` object is empty on the controller side. I have returned the custom array to `ajax` to check if controller function working and it's returning the response to `ajax` success.

Other functions on the same controller getting the `Request` data from `ajax` but not this function. I don't get any error so it's difficult to debug the issue

My Ajax call

```
$(document).on('click', 'i[id^="delete"]', function () {

        var alias_id = $(this).prop('id');
        //console.log(alias_id);

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: "{{ route('deletealiasname') }}",
            method: "post",
            data: {'alias_id': alias_id},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                console.log(alias_id);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/deletealiasname', 'API\UserProfileController@deleteAliasName')->name('deletealiasname');
```

Controller:

```
public function deleteAliasName(Request $request)
{
    $var = $request->all();
    return array($var);
}
```

Output of dd($request)

```
    POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/deletealiasname
----------------------------------------------

 ------------ ----------------------------------------------------
  date         Thu, 06 Jun 2019 17:52:53 +0000
  controller   "UserProfileController"
  source       UserProfileController.php on line 165
  file         app\Http\Controllers\API\UserProfileController.php
 ------------ ----------------------------------------------------

Illuminate\Http\Request {#43
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#282
    class: "Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider"
    this: Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider {#40 …}
    parameters: {
      $guard: {
        default: null
      }
    }
    use: {
      $app: Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2 …}
    }
    file: "C:\project\newglit\myglit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider.php"
    line: "83 to 85"
  }
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#284
    class: "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
    this: Illuminate\Routing\Router {#26 …}
    use: {
      $route: Illuminate\Routing\Route {#221 …}
    }
    file: "C:\project\newglit\myglit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php"
    line: "650 to 652"
  }
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45
    #parameters: []
  }
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44
    #parameters: []
  }
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#51
    #parameters: []
  }
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#47
    #parameters: array:29 [
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "C:\project\newglit\myglit\public"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "127.0.0.1"
      "REMOTE_PORT" => "56590"
      "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "PHP 7.1.29 Development Server"
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "SERVER_NAME" => "127.0.0.1"
      "SERVER_PORT" => "8000"
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/api/deletealiasname"
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "POST"
      "SCRIPT_NAME" => "/index.php"
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "C:\project\newglit\myglit\public\index.php"
      "PATH_INFO" => "/api/deletealiasname"
      "PHP_SELF" => "/index.php/api/deletealiasname"
      "HTTP_HOST" => "127.0.0.1:8000"
      "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
      "CONTENT_LENGTH" => "15"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" => "15"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
      "HTTP_ORIGIN" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
      "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" => "XMLHttpRequest"
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safar
i/537.36"
      "CONTENT_TYPE" => "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE" => "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
      "HTTP_REFERER" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/profile/"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate, br"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-US,en;q=0.9,nb;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_COOKIE" => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkdPR0NtcGNXdEJxKzVwZERheEZSMlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC9EbHBHSXM2U0c1TzdjUHhOT25BZ1RQeXdzd3l0WGFw
bmNhWWduakJFRU9ubVBcL3pJdzJMcTI1SCtqQnR4Sk05IiwibWFjIjoiYjk4Mzk3M2ZiOGJlOGZkOGNmYjk1NjBjZGQzNTY3YzIzOWUwNzliNDdjNjNhMzRhODZkOThmZGI2NzU
3MDc2OCJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IktNaHlnY29BZnI3VUlEcHpnUU1vU2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUkxWTkVWdHlLcEZGY0FDOXAxMWdaNHROa2szSUY3ZlhWRm94V2ox
ZWZSYlc4SDdcL3FSdUlVNGZ0YkFreHl4VHQiLCJtYWMiOiJlOGQ0MjYwZTRiN2ZkOTQwYWRmNTcxNjYyNTY0YmYyZjY5MjBkN2E3ZWMxZGM3YWViYzQ4ODcxYzUyZTg0MTE3In0
%3D"
      "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1559843573.3443
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1559843573
    ]
  }
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#48
    #parameters: []
  }
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#46
    #parameters: array:2 [
      "XSRF-TOKEN" => "eyJpdiI6IkdPR0NtcGNXdEJxKzVwZERheEZSMlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC9EbHBHSXM2U0c1TzdjUHhOT25BZ1RQeXdzd3l0WGFwbmNhWWduakJF
RU9ubVBcL3pJdzJMcTI1SCtqQnR4Sk05IiwibWFjIjoiYjk4Mzk3M2ZiOGJlOGZkOGNmYjk1NjBjZGQzNTY3YzIzOWUwNzliNDdjNjNhMzRhODZkOThmZGI2NzU3MDc2OCJ9"
      "laravel_session" => "eyJpdiI6IktNaHlnY29BZnI3VUlEcHpnUU1vU2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUkxWTkVWdHlLcEZGY0FDOXAxMWdaNHROa2szSUY3ZlhWRm94V2o
xZWZSYlc4SDdcL3FSdUlVNGZ0YkFreHl4VHQiLCJtYWMiOiJlOGQ0MjYwZTRiN2ZkOTQwYWRmNTcxNjYyNTY0YmYyZjY5MjBkN2E3ZWMxZGM3YWViYzQ4ODcxYzUyZTg0MTE3In
0="
    ]
  }
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49
    #headers: array:12 [
      "host" => array:1 [
        0 => "127.0.0.1:8000"
      ]
      "connection" => array:1 [
        0 => "keep-alive"
      ]
      "content-length" => array:1 [
        0 => "15"
      ]
      "accept" => array:1 [
        0 => "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
      ]
      "origin" => array:1 [
        0 => "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
      ]
      "x-requested-with" => array:1 [
        0 => "XMLHttpRequest"
      ]
      "user-agent" => array:1 [
        0 => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
      ]
      "content-type" => array:1 [
        0 => "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
      ]
      "referer" => array:1 [
        0 => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/profile/"
      ]
      "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
        0 => "gzip, deflate, br"
      ]
      "accept-language" => array:1 [
        0 => "en-US,en;q=0.9,nb;q=0.8"
      ]
      "cookie" => array:1 [
        0 => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkdPR0NtcGNXdEJxKzVwZERheEZSMlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC9EbHBHSXM2U0c1TzdjUHhOT25BZ1RQeXdzd3l0WGFwbmNhWWduak
JFRU9ubVBcL3pJdzJMcTI1SCtqQnR4Sk05IiwibWFjIjoiYjk4Mzk3M2ZiOGJlOGZkOGNmYjk1NjBjZGQzNTY3YzIzOWUwNzliNDdjNjNhMzRhODZkOThmZGI2NzU3MDc2OCJ9;
 laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IktNaHlnY29BZnI3VUlEcHpnUU1vU2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUkxWTkVWdHlLcEZGY0FDOXAxMWdaNHROa2szSUY3ZlhWRm94V2oxZWZSYlc4SD
dcL3FSdUlVNGZ0YkFreHl4VHQiLCJtYWMiOiJlOGQ0MjYwZTRiN2ZkOTQwYWRmNTcxNjYyNTY0YmYyZjY5MjBkN2E3ZWMxZGM3YWViYzQ4ODcxYzUyZTg0MTE3In0%3D"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/api/deletealiasname"
  #requestUri: "/api/deletealiasname"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: null
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

Comment: laravel version?

Comment: its Laravel 5.8

Comment: if youre using chome dev tools, does the network tab show any errors?

Comment: No, there is no error

Comment: are you reaching the deleteAliasName function?

Comment: try just `return $var;` instead of `return array($var);`

Comment: It does not make any change

Comment: dont post `dd($request)` post with `dd($var)` so can see parameters you passed with ajax is set or not properly and make `type: 'POST'` not `mehod`

Comment: According to your `dd($request)` no any parameters detect which you pass from `ajax` call

Answer (score 1):

i guess the issue is with `method:"post"`

because it's not `method` object, It's actually a `type`.

`type:"post"`

Try this one

```
$.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: "{{ route('deletealiasname') }}",
            type: "post",
            data: {'alias_id': alias_id},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                console.log(alias_id);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

ANd as you said you are using `laravel 5.8`. so you can start your dump server in terminal for debug. jsut hit command in terminal `php artisan dump-server` and `dd(#request)`

and see data is coming or not.

am sure its issue is with `method:"post"` just change it with `type:"post"`

Comment: I have changed the 'method' to 'type' but the result is the same. My other ajax call using method, not type and they are working fine

Comment: can you do a `dd($request)` in the controller method with `php artisan dump-server` so we can see on ajax call what request actually holding

Comment: I have updated my question with dd($request) output

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understood why it's happening but found a way to send data through ajax. I simply added a form element and appended my data to FormData and sent it as ajax data.

Form element

```
<form id="deleteAliasName" class="ui form" action="{{ route('deletealiasname') }}" method="post">
</form>
```

Ajax

```
var alias_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        formData = new FormData($('#deleteAliasName')[0]);
        formData.append('alias_id', alias_id);

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: "{{ route('deletealiasname') }}",
            type: "post",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

Now I receiving the data in controller request

*I won't mark it as accepted answer because I think it's a workaround.*

Comment: I saw nearly 20 questions about empty request and only this helped!